# add attachment to comments(message_part)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i basically have message and `message_part` models.  I installed `carrierwave`, generated picture uploader, have `:picture` columns in both `message` and `message_part` and I am able to upload image to `message`.  When i upload image to `message_part`, this image overwrites all other images and i have the same image in `message` and `message_part`.

my Message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :speaker
  has_many :messageparts
  has_many :message_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :message_categories
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

My message_part.rb

```
class Messagepart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :speaker
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

My message_part controller create

```
def create
    # @message = Message.find(params[:message_id])
    @messagepart = @message.messageparts.create(messagepart_params)
    @messagepart.speaker_id = current_speaker.id

    if @messagepart.save
      redirect_to message_path(@message)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

my message controller

```
def create
    @message = current_speaker.messages.build(message_params)
    if @message.save
    redirect_to messages_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end

  end
```

my view for message part

```
<%= simple_form_for([@message, @message.messageparts.build], html: { multipart: true } ) do |f| %>

<%= f.input :contentparttitle, label: "Part Title" %>
<%= f.input :contentpart, label: "Content Part", :as => :text, input_html: { :rows => 10, :class => "span6" } %>
<%= f.file_field :picture %>
<%= f.button :submit, label: "Add Parts", :class => 'btn-custom' %>
<% end %>
```

my view for message

```
<%= simple_form_for @message, html: { multipart: true }  do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Message Title"  %>
  <%= f.input :description, label: "Short Description" %>
  <%= f.input :content, :as => :text, :input_html => { 'rows' => 10} %>
  <strong>Category:</strong>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name do |cb| %>
    <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text} %>
    <% end %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

my picture uploader

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Comment: Can you put your code in your `PictureUploader`?

Comment: I just put picture Uploader code.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use two separate uploaders for two models, even if they're nearly identical. It will keep your objects nice and neatly named without worrying about overwrite.

And your form

```
<%= simple_form_for([@message, @message.messageparts.build], html: { multipart: true } ) do |f|%>
```

Will update both `@message` and `@message.messageparts`

Comment: So i can run rails generate uploader PicturePart? THen reference :picturepart in messagepart model? and that should take care of it?

Comment: Separate uploader is just a suggestion for the code structure. The problem is mainly related to the form